# How to recover from a long break, with proper nutrition?

Tags: strength, workout, nutrition, stronglifts

22/M/55kg/176cms

My last StrongLift 5*5 workout was on 28th Nov 2014, and I weighed 58.2 Kgs then. Since then I haven't worked out one bit and my diet is getting less by day (at least thats what I am feeling like) evident from my current weight.

Why I left- To concentrate on my job which involves- sitting for long hours at one place for 10 hours, 5 days a week. (Software Engineer)

Now I feel it was a bad decision, for a month or so I pulled alright without working out, but now I feel kind of unmotivated and lethargic and strangely a bit weaker.

Just as I was weighing in today, I decided to screw job and focus on my body, I want to get back at lifting, same StrongLift 5*5 program from the start, but I want to change my nutrition part.

This is where I need help, I want to build a diet regime, I want to eat those proper carbs and proteins 7 days a week. Please help me build that and recommend me sources from where I can even get ideas on what to cook. Please help me get back with a bang.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Well it is very easy actually, use some calorie calculator to find out how much of calories you need. Then find a proper macro balance, that you think will work for you. For example, mine is 40% protein 40% carbs 20% fat. As a person who does stronglifts you might not find it good for.

Good sources of carbs: oatmeal,buckwheat,greens(spinach,broccoli),fruit(kiwi,banana etc.),sweet potatoes and a lot of other whole wheat things. The easiest way to find good carb sources is to check their glycemic index.

Good sources of protein : Egg whites, some protein breads, oatmeal, beans, meat(chicken,tuna) dairy and if you think you can't fill your daily needs, protein powder. You can't replace food tho so only as an last option.

Good sources of fats : Tuna, dairy, nuts

I personally like to combine a lot of different things so for example one of my meals looks like this :

> 10 egg whites, 3 egg yolks, Spinach, Garlic, Chilli, Banana, sometimes sweet
>   potato.

Mix it all together and fry it a bit then put it into oven(with a pan that can handle the oven heat) or just fry it, doesn't matter.Add a bit cheese at the end(when in oven) Tastes awesome in my opinion. You can upgrade it even more with different spices like basil.

Eating healthy can be very easy, you just have to get creative.

Also, enough rest is very important. Try to get a good night sleep every night. I personally try to sleep at least 8-9 hours daily.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Will prepare a diet plan and hit the gym very soon!

Comment: Best of luck to you